# LinearGradient fillStyle isn't working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, data-visualization, fill, linear-gradients

I'm creating an audio visualization using web audio API and I've run into an issue where I'm unable to set a linear gradient to fill the rectangles in my visualization.

Here's the relevant code:

HTML

```
<div style="background-color: white; width:100%; height: 256px; position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">
    <canvas id="viz" style="background-color: white; height: 256px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
window.requestAnimationFrame =   window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
context = new AudioContext();
//set context for viz
var ctx = document.getElementById('viz').getContext('2d');
//create rainbow gradient and set fill style
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,256);
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FF0000');
gradient.addColorStop(0.2, '#FF7F00');
gradient.addColorStop(0.4, '#FFFF00');
gradient.addColorStop(0.55, '#00FF00');
gradient.addColorStop(0.7, '#0000FF');
gradient.addColorStop(0.85, '#4B0082');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#9400D3');
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

var vizAnalyser = context.createAnalyser();
vizAnalyser.fftsize=2048;
vizAnalyser.smoothingTimeConstant=.95;
navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
navigator.getMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false
}, function(localMediaStream) {
    //connect audio nodes
    source = context.createMediaStreamSource(localMediaStream);
    source.connect(vizAnalyser)
    draw();
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});



function draw() {
    //get frequency data from analyser node
    var bufferLength = vizAnalyser.frequencyBinCount;
    var hueData = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    vizAnalyser.getByteFrequencyData(hueData);
    var viz = document.getElementById("viz");

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, viz.width, 256);
    for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
    {
        ctx.fillRect(i * 3, 256-hueData[i], 2, 256);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

The visualization draws the rectangles in the proper locations with proper sizing, but they're black rather than the gradient.

[Vizualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s66kV.png)

I've looked around and I haven't been able to find what I'm doing wrong. 
Any insights would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be nothing wrong with your code.

```
window.requestAnimationFrame =   window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
context = new AudioContext();
//set context for viz
var ctx = document.getElementById('viz').getContext('2d');
//create rainbow gradient and set fill style
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,256);
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FF0000');
gradient.addColorStop(0.2, '#FF7F00');
gradient.addColorStop(0.4, '#FFFF00');
gradient.addColorStop(0.55, '#00FF00');
gradient.addColorStop(0.7, '#0000FF');
gradient.addColorStop(0.85, '#4B0082');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#9400D3');
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

var vizAnalyser = context.createAnalyser();
vizAnalyser.fftsize=2048;
vizAnalyser.smoothingTimeConstant=.95;
navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
navigator.getMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false
}, function(localMediaStream) {
    //connect audio nodes
    source = context.createMediaStreamSource(localMediaStream);
    source.connect(vizAnalyser)
    draw();
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});



function draw() {
    //get frequency data from analyser node
    var bufferLength = vizAnalyser.frequencyBinCount;
    var hueData = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    vizAnalyser.getByteFrequencyData(hueData);
    var viz = document.getElementById("viz");

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, viz.width, 256);
    for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
    {
        ctx.fillRect(i * 3, 256-hueData[i], 2, 256);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

Perhaps it is a browser issue.

It works perfectly in Chrome on my MacBook : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNPvyJ?editors=1111
[image]

Comment: Thanks! It must be a browser issue, but I did find a solution that made it work on my browser. If anybody else has this issue, I solved it by moving the "ctx.fillStyle = gradient;" line to be inside the draw function.